# Issue on Removing Index From Field by Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, attribute-index

Using ArcGIS 10.2 Desktop, I am trying to remove an attribute index from  my shapefile (`marten.shp`) as:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "D:\\Map\\Data"
arcpy.RemoveIndex_management("marten.shp", ["MamerMN"])
```

Here is the `marten.shp` Indexes

[image]

but I am getting this error 000192

[image]

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Based on your screenshot, "MamerMN" is unchecked, meaning there is no index for that field.  The reason you are getting an Invalid value for Index Name error is because there is no index by that name to remove.  You need to first check the attribute name to create the index.